# How to take multiple inputs(stdin) from python

Tags: python, stdin

This is the input in stdin. All the lines are on a new line.

```
3
27 8
4 0 0 2 6 1 4 6
19 6
6 4 3 6 0 0
4 3
1 1 1
```

First-line (i.e 3) indicates the number of queries i.e line 2(i.e 27 8) and line 3(i.e 4 0 0 2 6 1 4 6) is one query, line 4 and 5 is the second query, and line 6 and 7 is the third query. What I want to do is I want all the alternate lines in one **list** i.e line 2,4,6 in one list like `a=[[27,8],[19,6],[4 3]]` and line 3,5,7 in another list like `b=[[4,0,0,2,6,1,4,6],[6,4,3,6,0,0],[1,1,1]]`. From line second all the numbers have single space(`" "`) between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick, assuming your input is all numbers:

```py
a = []
b = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    a.append( list(map(int, input().split())) )
    b.append( list(map(int, input().split())) )
```

Comment: @AnkitBaria If you feel like one of the answers solves your problem, you may accept it by clicking on the check mark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

- t.txt

```
3
27 8
4 0 0 2 6 1 4 6
19 6
6 4 3 6 0 0
4 3
1 1 1
```

-script

```py
def convert_str_to_list(list1):
    l1_new=[]
    for i in list1:
        res=i.split(' ')
        a = list(map(int,res))
        l1_new.append(a)
    return l1_new

with open('t.txt','r') as file:
    lst_file=file.read().splitlines()
    l1 = lst_file[1::2]
# ['27 8', '19 6', '4 3']
    l2 = lst_file[2::2]
# ['4 0 0 2 6 1 4 6', '6 4 3 6 0 0', '1 1 1']
    l1=convert_str_to_list(l1)
    l2=convert_str_to_list(l2)
    
    print(l1)
#[[27, 8], [19, 6], [4, 3]]

    print(l2)
#[[4, 0, 0, 2, 6, 1, 4, 6], [6, 4, 3, 6, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```